# Which object's records get copied over when creating a sandbox?

Tags: sandbox-refresh

I've created a new sandbox and wanted to know which objects get their records copied over automatically by Salesforce whenever I create a sandbox?

Comment: What [type of Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&language=en_US) did you create?

Comment: developer pro and developer sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all of the settings and custom settings. So any object which contains records related to settings or custom settings get copied over by default when creating a sandbox.

The only thing I saw that didn't really follow this was the PriceBookEntry, PriceBook2, and Product2 objects which also get their records copied over by default. Here's a list of some of the objects I know for sure which get copied over:

- ApexClass
- ApexPage
- ApexTrigger
- FieldPermissions
- Folder
- Group
- IDEWorkspace
- ObjectPermissions
- OrgWideEmailAddress
- Organization
- PermissionSet
- Pricebook2
- PricebookEntry
- Product2
- Profile
- RecordType
- Scontrol
- StaticResource
- TraceFlag
- User
- UserRole